# Expected area of rectangle with normally distributed sides

Tags: probability, probability-theory

With random lengths $X ∼ G(0, 4)$ and $Y ∼ G(0, 5)$ (data in cm), construct a rectangle 2. Let $X$ and $Y$ be
independent. Let $Z = X -Y$ be the area of the rectangle (in cm ).

The area of the rectangle to be expected on average is in

$(A) (4.7, 5.2].\\ (B) (3.7, 4.2]\\(C) (4.2, 4.7].\\(D) (A)-(C) false$

My attempt:

I am not sure what the distribution $G$ means, but I assume it's the gaussian distribution.

So, I know that I need to search for $E(Z)=\int_zzf_Z(z)=\int(x-y)f_{X-Y}(x-y)$, however I'm not sure what to do exactly. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: It says that area is given by $Z = X - Y$ in cm. That does not make sense. It should have been $Z = XY$.

Comment: @MathLover That's how my textbook formulated the question

Comment: In any case $E(Z)$ will be zero. If it is average of area and area being positive, find $E(|Z|)$

Comment: @SlimShady For future reference, Gaussian distribution is almost universally denoted using symbol $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ with parameters denoting mean and standards deviation respectively.

Since $Z=X-Y$ doesn't make sense it is also possible that there's simply a typo. What textbook are you using. Have you checked errata?